# In Power BI, How can I plot a yeartarget (one number in a table) in fixed fractions over twelve months?

Tags: powerbi, dax, target

I have a bar chart that shows cumulative results per month over one year.

*jan(5) feb(12) mar(15) apr(21).....dec(122)*

I have a target value for that year. (120)

I don't like a horizontal line plotted as the target.

How do I plot it as a diagonal line from january to december?
ie if the target is 120 for the year I'd like to see a line going through 10 in jan, 20 in feb,..., 120 in dec.

In DAX I tried something like:

````
calculate(
    sum(sales[target]), 
    FILTER(
        ALL('Datetable'[monthnumber]),
        'Datetable'[monthnumber] <= MAX(datetable[monthnumber]))
        )```
````

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the Line and Stacked Column Visual might give you what you need.

You can make a target measure like I did in the picture below:

```
targetline = 10*SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[Month Number])
```

[image: line and stacked column chart]

Comment: That's it! Thanks!